# AWK doesn't filter number 100 in decimal form (100.000) in output locale

Tags: bash, awk, locale

First of all, thank you everyone for your help. I have a problem filtering with AWK with the value 100.000 which is the same same as 100, but is with decimals. I have this file:

```
1   100
2   100.000
3   99.874
4   67.321
```

This is my code:

```
cat example.txt | awk '$2 >= 70 {print $2}'
```

The output generated is the following

```
100
99.874
```

As you can see the value 100.000 will also have to appear. My awk version is mawk 1.3.4 20200120

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in GNU `awk` When I run this I get `100.000` in output. Which version of `awk` you are using and what is o.s for you? Kindly do mention these details too, thank you.

Comment: you can lose the `cat` and the pipe, just `awk ... file.txt`

Comment: It appears the same result

Comment: My awk version is mawk 1.3.4 20200120

Comment: Add output of `locale` to your question (no comment).

Comment: while the accepted answer (`LC_NUMERIC=C`) addresses this particular issue, you may want to consider installing an up-to-date version of `GNU awk` to eliminate other issues that may crop up (in the future) from using `mawk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior depends on your `locale` settings.

I suggest:

```
LC_NUMERIC=C mawk '$2 >= 70 {print $2}' example.txt
```